# TypeError: React hook causing error Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ajax, http, react-hooks

I am facing this issue (**TypeError: Object(...) is not a function**) when I am trying to use **Axios** with react hook **useEffect**, I searched a lot but did not find any solution why the code is not working fine.

It causing error when I am sending ajax request with useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        });
}, []);
```

[image]

Here is my complete functional component code:

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Post from '../../components/Post/Post';
import FullPost from '../../components/FullPost/FullPost';
import NewPost from '../../components/NewPost/NewPost';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Blog.module.css';


const  Blog  =  (props) =>  {

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        });
}, []);



    return (
        <div>
           
            <section className="Posts">
                <Post/>
                <Post/>
                <Post/>
            </section>
            <section>
                <FullPost/>
            </section>
            <section>
                <NewPost/>
            </section>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Where do you get `users` from?

Comment: Sorry, I removed users, it's not part of the component

Comment: without `useEffect ` ajax request working fine

Comment: As I see it is not any issue in your code maybe the issue is in Blog's childs component